# vite + react how to import or get images from asset folder using .env

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend, vite, react-fullstack

I am working on a project like social media application , here i am using vite reactJs to build frontend. My pictures of users and posts are in assets folder in Public dir. images are in jpeg.
i want to use .env to create a key and to access the images in post and etc places.
currently i am using a dummy data where i put address of pic.
[This is my assets folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k6wC.png)

This is how i made a key in .env to access the images in assets
**VITE_PUBLIC_FOLDER = http://localhost:5173/assets/**

I have updated my vite config file too likewise :
**'process.env.VITE_PUBLIC_FOLDER': JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_PUBLIC_FOLDER)
}**

```
<span className="postText w-full p-2">{post?.desc}</span>
<img
className="postImg w-full max-h-500 object-contain rounded-3xl"
src={ post.photo }
alt="photo" />
{/* <img className="postImg w-full max-h-500 object-contain rounded-3xl" src={img1} alt="" /> */}
```

above is where i add photo . here post.photo is like post is a parameter given which goes in dummy data in post and inside post is a photo where link address is given:

Post example :
{
id: 2,
photo: 'posts/1.jpeg',
date: "15 mins ago",
userId: 2,
like: 2,
comment: 1,
},

I did configure vite config file and used import.meta.env and called it and still dosen't work

Comment: Shouldn't the pictures and posts of users be in a live database rather than your project folder?

Comment: yea i am keeping it currently in a file ik they shud be live. I was just checking if stuff is working or not